# What is the most reliable shape representation for the purpose of detecting humans shapes?

Tags: computer-vision, shape-analysis, shape-discriptor, human-detection

The requirement of the algorithm is to detect human shapes. While the standard HoG or Harr cascade can be used, I am exploring whether the human shape - which primarily includes face+neck+upper-torso shape as some kind of template and identify human shape.

It will facilitate human detection in extremely low light condition where practically all i one can see is a "shadow like" shape of the human.

I am looking at images that looks [image: something like this].

Any suggestions?

PS: I do not have computational power (GPU) to run deep learning. So looking for traditional vision based algorithm.